# security of a function that queries a sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, security

Would the code below be considered "secure"?

```
Public Function GetManager(ByVal uname As String) As String
    Dim strSelect = String.Format("SELECT UserName FROM aspnet_Users INNER JOIN Hierarchy ON UserId = LineManagerID WHERE StaffID = (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = '{0}')", uname)
    Dim cmdCommand = New SqlCommand(strSelect, _connection)
    GetManager = cmdCommand.ExecuteScalar()
End Function
```

I'm looking specifically at the part..

```
 where UserName = {'0'}, uname
```

Am I right in saying that the apostrophes open me up to some potential scripting attacks?

Many thanks.

DS

Comment: Use parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: hi - thanks for replying so quickly - could you offer a modified example to illustrate your point here, please?

Comment: What control do you have on the parameter passed to this function? Could someone write `uname=';DROP TABLE ASPNET_USERS;--`

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not secure. Your uname-parameter will be inserted into the string that is the SQL command.
An evil user could send any string that messes with your sql.

The best thing is to use parameterized queries: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)